# spark 1.4.0 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsedMillis()J

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, guava

I'm using spark 1.4.0 / hadoop 2.6.0 (just for hdfs) and when running the Scala SparkPageRank example (*examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkPageRank.scala*), I encounter the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsedMillis()J
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$distinct$2.apply(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$distinct$2.apply(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.distinct(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPageRank$.main(SparkPageRank.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPageRank.main(SparkPageRank.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:621)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I'm not extremely familiar with java, but it seems that it's a [guava](https://github.com/google/guava) version issue

The following information could be helpfup:

```
$ find ./spark -name *.jars | grep guava
./lib_managed/bundles/guava-16.0.1.jar
./lib_managed/bundles/guava-14.0.1.jar
```

part of the examples/pom.xml file:

```
...
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.6</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
...
```

And indeed it seems that the class does not contain the problematic method:

```
$ javap -p /mnt/spark/examples/target/streams/\$global/assemblyOption/\$global/streams/assembly/7850cb6d36b2a6589a4d27ce027a65a2da72c9df_5fa98cd1a63c99a44dd8d3b77e4762b066a5d0c5/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.class

Compiled from "Stopwatch.java"
public final class com.google.common.base.Stopwatch {
  private final com.google.common.base.Ticker ticker;
  private boolean isRunning;
  private long elapsedNanos;
  private long startTick;
  public static com.google.common.base.Stopwatch createUnstarted();
  public static com.google.common.base.Stopwatch createUnstarted(com.google.common.base.Ticker);
  public static com.google.common.base.Stopwatch createStarted();
  public static com.google.common.base.Stopwatch createStarted(com.google.common.base.Ticker);
  public com.google.common.base.Stopwatch();
  public com.google.common.base.Stopwatch(com.google.common.base.Ticker);
  public boolean isRunning();
  public com.google.common.base.Stopwatch start();
  public com.google.common.base.Stopwatch stop();
  public com.google.common.base.Stopwatch reset();
  private long elapsedNanos();
  public long elapsed(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit);
  public java.lang.String toString();
  private static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit chooseUnit(long);
  private static java.lang.String abbreviate(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit);
}
```

I would like to understand better the issue, and if possible learn how to fix it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `elapsedMilis()` has been removed in Guava 16. (Or was planned to be removed - anyway there is no method with this name on your listing.)

As far I remember there should be something like `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS` in guava 16, or you can convert manually by divading 1000000000.0.

Comment: Good note, thank you. However the answer I'm looking for details why the hadoop/spark combination I'm using is not working, and what can I do to either fix it or upgrade it.

Comment: Well exclusion in the pom.xml means (more or less) you do not add the specified jar into the classpath when building the project. Maybe that's the issue? So maybe you should remove the exclusion part? 
May it be that the app ignores the older version of the library?
Try to read the maven docu to the topic: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted, to be fair! the setup I'm now using and which seems to be working is spark 1.4.0 and hadoop 2.5.2, using  the pre-built spark version.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading Hadoop from 2.6.0 to 2.6.5. In my case it solved the problem with Stopwatch while using the function HBaseAdmin.tableExists (other dependencies: Hbase 1.2.0, Spark 2.0.1, Scala 2.11.8 ), although the solution for this problem in Hbase is planned to be released in 1.3.0, which is currently not available for production [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14963)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Spark 2.4.4, and still having this problem! I don't really need to see this logging output anyway, so I simply changed the logging level for the class in question:

```
 <logger name="org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</logger>
```